# Finding the file name with maximum numeric suffix

Tags: regex, perl, perl-data-structures

I have a list of files with `mmddyyyy_nnnnn` format. How do I find file with the highest number in postfix `nnnnn` using perl?

Example: for these three files

```
11232014_00001
11232014_00002
11232014_00003
```

I want to return file name for 00003.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my @files = qw(11232014_00001 11242013_00002 11232012_00003);
my ($highest)= 
    map { $_->[0] }
     sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
      map { [$_, /(\d+)$/] }
       @files;
say $highest;
```

**Output:**

```
11232012_00003
```

Answer (score 2):

I hate using `sort` for obviously linear algorithm (you don't actually need to sort your list, you only want to find a maximum), so here is a solution using good old `foreach` loop and no sorting at all:

```
use strict;
use Modern::Perl;

my @files = qw(11232014_00001 11242013_00002 11232012_00003 22222222_00001);
my ($max_value, $max);
foreach (@files) {
        if (/_(\d+)$/ && (!defined $max_value || $1 > $max_value)) {
                $max_value = $1;
                $max = $_;
        }
}
say $max;
```

Answer (score 1):

Full sort as in [ST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) is not efficient for larger lists *when only looking for maximal value*, thus `reduce` from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) core module might be optimal solution,

```
use List::Util 'reduce';

my @files = qw(11232014_00001 11242013_00002 11232012_00003);
my ($max) = reduce {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map /(\d+)$/, $a,$b;
    $aa > $bb ? $a : $b
  }
  @files;
```

Similar approach by using `max_by` from [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy)

```
use List::UtilsBy 'max_by';

my @files = qw(11232014_00001 11242013_00002 11232012_00003);
my $max = max_by { ( /(\d+)$/ )[0] } @files;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you dealing with fixed width filenames, I'd suggest reformatting and sorting by alpha:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = qw(11232014_00001 11242014_00002 11232015_00003);

my @sorted = sort {
    local ( $a, $b ) = map { s/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/$3$1$2/r or die "Invalid format: $_" } ( $a, $b );
    $a cmp $b;
} @files;

print "$sorted[-1]";
```

Outputs:

```
11232015_00003
```